# Why does deleting of many BLOBs lock MySQL database with state: enforcing dict cache limit?

Tags: mysql, blob, innodb, sql-delete

I need to delete about 400 rows from the MySQL table with columns:

`id - INT(11)
training_id - INT(11)
estimator_blob - LONGBLOB`

The size of `estimator_blob` is 32 Mb.

It seems that a query like this:

`DELETE FROM estimator WHERE training_id IN (1, 2, ..., 400);`

locks the database. After executing this query all new queries inserting results to this table are executed extremely slow.

In the status of database (`mysql> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`) I have this message:

`Process ID=2600, Main thread ID=139974149678848, state: enforcing dict cache limit`

**What exactly does "enforcing dict cache limit" mean?** Is it the reason of this "lock"?

Increasing the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` didn't help.

I'm using MySQL 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 on the machine with 70Gb RAM.

Comment: is training_id indexed? You could also try
* increase total number of file handles available to MySQL
* increase number of file handles for InnoDB

Comment: Yes, it is. Actually it is a foreign key and I don't use `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Ok, I'll try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`enforcing dict cache limit` is a background status for InnoDB processes. In this state InnoDB checks for the usage of table dictionary cache (e.g table metadata) memory consumption and cleans up the dictionary cache if required.

As per the guidance provided by MySQL developers for [bug report 84424](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84424):

> You have to do several things in order to alleviate the problem:
>
> - increase the additional memory pool
> - increase total number of file handles available to MySQL
> - increase number of file handles for InnoDB
> - improve performance of the I/O on your operating system

You probably need to restart your server to fully recover from the issue.

Comment: Ugh.  The other solution might be to break it up into 1-row deletes with autocommit=ON.